# How to add a watermark to a .Net DLL or EXE (to trace the copyright)?

Tags: c#, .net, security, obfuscation, cracking

I know that ultimately any .NET dll/exe can be "decompiled" via reverse-engineering

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a watermark to it in order to discourage piracy ? (i.e. to add an unique product identifier).

How does it works, and how secure is it?

EDIT : I think that a hack/crack usually applies to a small part of the original assembly and so I guess that some watermark can be left.

Answer (score 2):

While there are a large number of ways to "curb" behavior like you are describing (i.e. "Reverse Engineering", "Deobfuscation", etc.), there really isn't guaranteed way to prevent it entirely.

In the .NET realm, nearly every obfuscation tool out there has a "deobfuscation" counterpart that can be used to take a peek behind the scenes. While some do a much better job than others, it'll be more than enough for someone dedicated (and proficient) enough.

With regards to watermarks, once the pirating party has broken through the layer of protection (be it obfuscation or some other technique), they'll be able to simply replace any logos or imagery with their own.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mean "cracking" you mean "reverse engineering", and once someone does that to your assembly (.DLL or .EXE), they can copy sections of your code which is just text after all.

There's no way to protect against that.  You can't embed a watermark or anything in text that is being copied from a text file.

Comment: yes I mean reverse engineering. Regarding your point, can we imagine a way to change the source code by (automatically) renaming differently the local variables or something like that  ? or to add the watermark in the logo/images ?

Comment: Sure you can change the source code which is called obfuscation.  I assume you know about that because you tagged your question with it.  That still wouldn't stop someone from copying your code and changing the names to whatever they want.  It just makes it harder for them to understand what it does because there are no longer any meaningful names.  I don't know about watermarks in images.  Sure, I guess.  That's outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @roryap Thanks I was thinking of an obfuscation procedure which simultaneously watermark the code by rearranging the code differently (or something similar).